# Pattern overlapping, why is it happening?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a file OptionList.hs, with a new datatype named OptionList. I Want to hide the EmptyOpt when an OptionList is showed:

```
module OptionList (
    OptionList,
    voidOption,
    (+:)
) where


data OptionList a b = EmptyOpt | OptionList { optListHead :: a, optListTail :: b } deriving (Read)

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (OptionList a b) where
    show (OptionList voidOption a) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
    show (OptionList a voidOption) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
    show (OptionList a b) = "{"++ (show a) ++ ", " ++ (show b) ++"}"
    show voidOption = ""




voidOption::(OptionList Int Int)
voidOption = EmptyOpt



(+:) :: a -> b -> (OptionList a b)
infixr 5 +:
t1 +: t2 = OptionList t1 t2
```

And then I have the main file `todo.hs`

```
import OptionList


main = do
    print ( 0 +: "test" +: voidOption )
```

But the compiler is telling that the pattern matching in OptionList.hs are overlapped:

```
OptionList.hs:12:9: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘show’:
        show (OptionList a voidOption) = ...
        show (OptionList a b) = ...
```

And when I execute it, it is indeed overlapped. It produces the following output:

```
{{}}
```

(I wanted it to be `{0, {"test"}}`)

But why are these pattern overlapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the line

```
show (OptionList voidOption a) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
```

`voidOption` is a fresh local variable, like `a` is. It bears no relations with the `voidOption` variable defined below. Essentially, the line above is equivalent to

```
show (OptionList b a) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
```

hence, it always matches and overlaps with the following lines.

It's easy to remember this if we regards all the variables in patterns as variables *defined by the pattern*. In a sense they are values going "out" the pattern, not "in".

Turning on warnings (`-Wall`) should warn you about this mistake, since the new local binding for `voidOption` shadows the global one.

In patterns, you should use the `EmptyOpt` constructor instead. E.g.

```
show (OptionList EmptyOpt a) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code as suggested but more errors appeared. See my edit

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann That "update" would be better as a new question, since it is about a new problem with new code. But a small hint: in your `show` implementation, you have two arbitrary types `a` and `b`, and all that you know is that they can be `show`n. Why do you think you can pattern-match them against a constructor of type `OptionList`?

Comment: Ok! Sorry. I'll make a new question